# Dúvida básica em C# (Sons)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiladores

sou novo no fórum e novo programador C# também.

Fiz um software básico pra faculdade; uma cafeteira. e nele usei sons, porém eu indiquei o som em ("C:/users/...") o caminho no meu Pc.

Quando eu faço o ".exe" deste aplicativo, quando executo em outro pc que não seja o meu ele dá miss no som e fecha.

Sei que a pergunta é besta, mas como resolvo isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ao invés de usar o caminho direto do PC, Cria uma pasta na raiz do projeto chamada "Sons" todos os sons que vai usar no aplicativo você joga la.

Quando for usar o som você busca da seguinte forma:

```
//Monta o caminho dos sons
var caminhoSons = Application.StartupPath + @"\Sons";

//Valida se a pasta existe
if (!Directory.Exists(caminhoSons))
{
    //Se não existir cria a pasta na raiz do projeto
    Directory.CreateDirectory(caminhoSons);
}

//Pega o som especifico
var musica1 = caminhoSons + @"\Musica.Mp3";
```

O comando `Application.StartupPath` obtem a pasta onde seu projeto estiver rodando, Então pode estar em qualquer PC, Ao até mesmo num Pen Drive (E:,F:) que ele vai obter o caminho correto do projeto, E ai tendo a pasta sons dentro da pasta do projeto sempre achará o caminho certo.

Comment: Sensacional! Funcionou aqui de forma perfeita! Muito grato